# Following an action link with a character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My code originally looked like this (pretty stock)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
```

I decided to wrap the edit line in an `if` statement so that it would be shown only if a condition were true

```
@if (item.UserCanEdit())
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
}
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
```

But now I get a compile error

> | is an Invalid expression term

and

> ; is expected.

What am I missing here? Something simple no doubt...

Comment: more detail see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Comment: you have to remove @ on first place and add @: in front of | symbol or <text>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@:` before `|` inside the `if` block to tell Razor that `|` is a content block instead of a C# syntax

```
@if (item.UserCanEdit())
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) @:|
}
```